# Loading resized image with cv2.imread failed with TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, classification, typeerror

I'm new in this community and with Python too.

#### Intention

I'm trying to do image classification with Python.

Because I have some problems directly loading the data, I added following steps in preparation:

- I have 16'000 images in a folder and they have different number of pixel.
- That's why I want to resize them into a square shape
- Then I want to convert the squared image into a matrix

#### Code

```
import cv2
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
import glob

food_imgs = np.zeros(300*300*3)

for i, img in enumerate(glob.glob("Downloads/Food-11/training/*.jpg")):
    if i == 5:
        break
fo = Image.open(img)
fo = fo.resize((300, 300))
food_imgs = np.c_[food_imgs, cv2.imread(fo).flatten()]
```

#### Error

Loading the squared image failed.
The error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-b5adecbdc8f9> in <module>()
      6     fo = Image.open(img)
      7     fo = fo.resize((300, 300), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
----> 8     food_imgs = np.c_[food_imgs, cv2.imread(fo).flatten()]

TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, Image found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `cv2.imread` expects a file name as parameter

Comment: @saulspatz Agree with you, the found duplicate can be used to simplify, but is not the issue here. Maybe the question's title was also misleading to the dup. Intention is "to do image classification" and error to solve is wrong argument-type. Couldn't we use  `fo.flatten()` directly instead `cv2.imread(fo).flatten()` ? Thus **voted to reopen** and answer with a fix for `TypeError` and obsolete `imread`.

Comment: this question is almost 6 years old. OP's issue was that they didn't understand how to use PIL or OpenCV. OP tried to pass a PIL Image to `cv.imread`, which is a very simple error. cv.imread requires a _path_ string for the argument, not a PIL Image. OP's task can be accomplished without OpenCV. I agree that this should be (stay) closed as a duplicate.